# Flex Layout Height Issue

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am facing issue to increase and decrease the height of div where I apply `fxFlex`. I provided dynamic height to container. How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance.
[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvbrub)

```
<div class="container">
   <div fxFlex="30"> Some Text </div>
   <div fxFlex="40"> Some Text </div>
   <div fxFlex="30"> Some Text </div>
</div>
```

*Note*: Height provided container dynamically (on window size / resize)

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Maybe add in your current attempt so that we can have a better understanding of the problem. It'll be a bonus if you could show us the current state and the expected state. Thanks.

Comment: Demo added for your reference.

Comment: What are you trying to set the height to? 100% of window height?

Comment: yes 100% of window height.

Comment: Can you show an example ( a drawing) of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do using `fxFlexFill`: [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-flex-layout-height-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 20px" fxFlexFill fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <div fxFlex="30"><mat-card>Some Text</mat-card></div>
  <div fxFlex="40"><mat-card>Some Text</mat-card></div>
  <div fxFlex="30"><mat-card>Some Text</mat-card></div>
</div>
```

`fxFlexFill` allows you to set the height of the `div` according to what it can take.

So I added the following `CSS` for your `HTML` page to take a maximum height depending on your screen.

```
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0;}
```

DEMO:

[image]